# Create an aggregated offset entry to a listof entries

Tags: sql, insert

I have dBase that collects financial data that builds a string to upload to an ERP system.

Example:

```
Receipt,   Amount,  Area,  Code, FieldA, GLAccount,     UploadString
   12      50.00    123ABC  0001  1714   123456      50.00 123ABC 0001 1714 123456  
   13      60.00    123ABC  0001  1714   123456      60.00 123ABC 0001 1714 123456
   14      70.00    123ABC  0001  1714   123456      70.00 123ABC 0001 1714 123456
```

To create an offset string, I use

```
Insert into MyTable (Amount,Area,Code,GLAccount)
Select Area
Code
GLAccount ='654321'
sum(Amount*-1)
from MyTable
GroupBy 
Area,Code,GLAccount
```

Resulting in an line looking like

```
[Receipt],[Amount],[Area], [Code], [FieldA],  [GLAccount],        [UploadString]
   Null   -180.00   123ABC  0001    Null         654321      50.00 123ABC 0001 NULL 654321
```

The Null in the FieldA doesn't allow to build the upload string.

I have been doing a lot of reading on derived tables, but I can't get the syntax right.

Would any of you know how I can populate all the fields in the table, while only using a few of the fields to generate the offset amount?

I would like to see:

```
[Amount],[Area], [Code], [FieldA],  [GLAccount],        [UploadString]
-180.00   123ABC  0001    1714         654321      50.00 123ABC 0001 1714 654321
```

Comment: That SQL statement won't run on any RDBMS I'm aware of (syntax error due to missing commas in the `SELECT` list), and it appears to be mismatched to the `INSERT` list too.  You seem to be setting `GLAccount` for _all_ rows, regardless of whether the source row has that value or not (auditors may kill you).  How the heck are you _also_ getting `UploadString`, which isn't present in that `SELECT` list, and is a non-aggregate besides.  To get `FieldA` to not be null, you need to put it in the `SELECT` list (aggregated or in the `GROUP BY`).  Why is the amount negative?

Comment: I construct the upload string by concatenating fields.The Insert Statement I displayed is only a representation of what I am trying to do, as there are too many fields involved and is not visually presentable on here. This runs for only one group that may have multiple entries, so the Setting of the Account number is fixed, although if you are aware of any resources I can read/learn by I'd appreciate that greatly.

Comment: The amount is negative as it is the offset to the aggregated individual journal entries made from the other entries.

Comment: If you want to reduce your problem size, fine, but you need to make it into a _working_ one.  Compile/syntax errors aren't something we should be dealing with (generally).  They just confuse the question and make people focus on the wrong thing.  Please edit your question into something that can actually be run, say on [SQL Fiddle](sqlfiddle.com).  Why do you think you need the negative sum?  What does that gain you?